# Avoid repetition in user-defined template specializations

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-specialization, specialization

I'm creating [a library](https://github.com/SuperV1234/SSVUtilsJson) that wraps [JsonCpp](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/) allowing the user to write **template specializations** to define conversions from `Json::Value` to `T` and from `T` to `Json::Value`. It works, but the specialization syntax is very inelegant and I would like to improve it by avoiding repetitions.

Here's how you can currently define a conversion:

```
namespace ssvuj // my library's namespace
{
    namespace Internal
    {
        template<> struct FromJson<sf::Color>
        {
            inline static sf::Color conv(const Obj& mObj)
            {
                return sf::Color(as<float>(mObj, 0), as<float>(mObj, 1), as<float>(mObj, 2), as<float>(mObj, 3));
            }
        };

        template<> struct ToJson<sf::Color>
        {
            inline static Obj conv(const sf::Color& mValue)
            {
                Obj result;
                set(result, 0, mValue.r);
                set(result, 1, mValue.g);
                set(result, 2, mValue.b);
                set(result, 3, mValue.a);
                return result;
            }
        };
    }
}

// example usage
ssvuj::Obj objColor; // this Json object contains sf::Color data
ssvuj::Obj objEmpty; // this Json object is empty

sf::Color colorFromObj{ssvuj::as<sf::Color>(objColor)}; // color is initialized by "deserializing" the Json object
ssvuj::set(objEmpty, colorFromObj); // the color is "serialized" into the empty Json object
```

Problems I notice:

- The repetition of the type, `sf::Color` in this case
- The necessity of using a struct specialization with a `static void` (I tried specializing functions, but it doesn't work for partial specializations such as `T = std::vector<T>`)

The only way I can think of making this less verbose and more elegant is a macro, but there probably is something I can do without using the preprocessor. Ideas?

Comment: Why do you want two types for the conversion rather than a single type that offers `fromJson` and `toJson` functions? Alternatively you could try to use overloads (rather than specializations) for the types you want to support... If you enable ADL at the same time, user code will become much simpler.

Comment: where is your struct with a `static void` function?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: you're right, I guess it would be much better with a single `Converter<T>` struct. I'll test it out and I'll let you know if I'm satisfied with it so that you can post an answer I can accept.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: I like your solution. Please post it as an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: @VittorioRomeo: But I don't like it (at least not what I think you like out of the two options I mentioned above). :) I would opt to use regular function overloads, with a templated implementation for the generic case and possible template overloads (more specialized than the generic) for the containers... [BTW, you can answer yourself and accept your answer if you want]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was implementing `template<typename T> class Converter;`, that the user can specialize.

Example:

```
template<> struct Converter<sf::Color>
{
    using T = sf::Color;
    inline static void fromObj(T& mValue, const Obj& mObj)
    {
        mValue.r = as<float>(mObj, 0);
        mValue.g = as<float>(mObj, 1);
        mValue.b = as<float>(mObj, 2);
        mValue.a = as<float>(mObj, 3);
    }
    inline static void toObj(Obj& mObj, const T& mValue)
    {
        set(mObj, 0, mValue.r);
        set(mObj, 1, mValue.g);
        set(mObj, 2, mValue.b);
        set(mObj, 3, mValue.a);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

For the `ToJson` direction, you don't need a template at all - it's sufficient to overload a free function on the input type:

```
inline static Obj conv(const sf::Color& mValue)
{
    Obj result;
    set(result, 0, mValue.r);
    set(result, 1, mValue.g);
    set(result, 2, mValue.b);
    set(result, 3, mValue.a);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I don't think it would work, [because I have a "fallback" case if there is not an explicit specialization](https://github.com/SuperV1234/SSVUtilsJson/blob/master/include/SSVUtilsJson/Utils/UtilsJson.h#L39). Am I correct?

Comment: That only works if `T` is implicitly convertible to `Obj`, right? So either just write a fallback overload `Obj conv(Obj const& o) { return o; }`, or write a free function template: that should _always_ be a worse match than an explicitly-typed overload.

Comment: No, it works if `T` can be assigned to `Obj`, I believe. Anyway, I tried your solution but it doesn't work - even if a "more specific" overload is present, it tries to match the fallback `template<typename T>` overload.

Comment: Can you post (possibly in a separate question) some minimal code that shows the problem? I can't take your whole lib, guess what changes you've made, and test that ...